# Python Input Function Crashes Ubuntu Terminal When Run As a .desktop File

Tags: python, ubuntu-20.04

I have a .desktop file set up so that I can run my python program to easily run my hosted servers, but when I run the program after I specify the game the terminal crashes.

Ubuntu Version 20.04
Python Version 3.10.6

Python Code:

```
import os


sv = int(input("Run What Server?\n1) Minecraft\n2) Garry's Mod\n"))
game = ""

try:
    if (sv == 1):
        game = "Minecraft"
    
    elif (sv == 2):
        game = "Garry's Mod"
    
except ValueError:
    print("invalid choice")
    exit(0)

print("Opening " + game + "...")

if (game == "Minecraft"):
    os.system("cd Servers/Minecraft && ./run.sh")
    
elif (game == "Garry's Mod"):
    os.system("cd Servers/Gmod && ./run.sh")
```

.desktop File:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash python3
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Server Launcher
Type=Application
Exec=python3 /home/yomie/.local/share/applications/Servers.py
Terminal=true
```

Things I have tried:

- Builtins package
- Reinstalling Ubuntu completely
- Updating and Upgrading
- Reinstalling Python 3.10.6
- Updating to Python 3.11
- Changing /usr/bin/gnome-terminal to use 3.11, 3.10.6, 3.10, and 3.8

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/262861/how-to-change-working-directory-when-open-a-file-with-double-clicking-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found to this problem is rewriting the code into another language.

I rewrote mine in C++ and now it suddenly works!

Edit: If I find a solution to this problem that isn't rewriting code I will post it here!